# Server Unable to listen to Client, after Client restarts

Tags: sockets

I am trying to build a server-client model, where client will send some command and server will execute those command and results will be shown.Server has to be made to handle multiple client requests.

But what is happening, server starts perfectly and is listening at desired port.When, the first time the client program is started, the server perfectly listens to all commands from it.But suppose now, I press Ctrl+C and make client program quit and restart it,now, the server is not listening to any command from the client.I am unable to make out why.

Server Code :

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;
#define BUFF_SIZE 1024
#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0
#define EXIT_FAILURE 1
#define NO_USER -9999

char *SERVER_IP[2];
int SERVER_PORT[2];
static int global_uid=NO_USER;

void login(string,string);
int verifyCredentials(string,string);
void addUser(string,string);
void logout();
int groupExistence(int group_id);
void createGroup(int group_id);


void createGroup(int group_id)
{
 /* if(!groupExistence(group_id) && global_uid!=NO_USER)
  {
    string filename1=to_string(group_id)+"_users.txt";
    string filename2=to_string(group_id)+"_pending_users.txt";
    ofstream file1,file2;
    file1.open(filename1);
    file1<<global_uid<<"\n";
    file1.close();
    file2.open(filename2);
    file2.close();
  }
  else cout<<group_id<<": Group already Exists!"<<endl; */
  cout<<"User active is : "<<global_uid<<endl;
}

int groupExistence(int group_id)
{
  ifstream infile("All_Groups.txt");
  int gid;
  while(infile>>gid)
  {
    if(gid==group_id) 
    { infile.close();
      return 1;
    }
  }
  infile.close();
  return 0;

}

void logout()
{
  if(global_uid!=NO_USER)
  {
     cout<<global_uid<<" logged out!."<<endl;
    global_uid=NO_USER;

  }

}


void login(string user_id,string password)
{
  if(verifyCredentials(user_id,password))
  {
     global_uid=atoi(user_id.c_str());
     cout<<"User : "<<global_uid<<" logged in."<<endl;
  }

  else cout<<"Login failed.Try again!"<<endl;

}


int verifyCredentials(string user_id,string password)
{

    ifstream infile("user_info.txt");
  string a,b;
  while(infile>>a>>b)
  {
       if(user_id.compare(a)==0 && password.compare(b)==0) return 1;
  }
  infile.close();
  return 0;
}

void addUser(string user_id,string password)
{
  ofstream oft;
  oft.open ("user_info.txt",ios::app); // Append mode
    oft<< user_id<<" "<<password<<"\n"; // Writing data to file
    oft.close(); // Closing the file
}



void startServer(char *Server_IP,int Server_Port)
{
    int server_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port=htons(Server_Port);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(Server_IP);
   int addrlen=sizeof(addr);

   bind(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
   listen(server_fd,20);

   int sockfd=accept(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,(socklen_t *)&addrlen);
}

char ** commandParser(char input[1024])
{
    char *token;
    char **tokens=(char **)malloc(sizeof(char *)*10);
    int index=1;
    token=strtok(input," ");
        //printf("IP : ");
        tokens[0]=token;

        while(token!=NULL)
        {

            token=strtok(NULL," ");
            if(token!=NULL)
            { 
                tokens[index++]=token;

             }
        }

        return tokens;

}

void commandHandler(char input[1024])
{
    int length=strlen(input);
    char **command_tokens;

    command_tokens=commandParser(input);

    //printf("\n Command is : %s\n",command_tokens[0]);

    if(strcmp(command_tokens[0],"create_user")==0)
    {
        addUser(command_tokens[1],command_tokens[2]);
    cout<<command_tokens[1]<<": USER created!."<<endl;
    }

  if(strcmp(command_tokens[0],"login")==0)
  {
    login(command_tokens[1],command_tokens[2]);
  }

  if(strcmp(command_tokens[0],"logout")==0)
  {
    logout();
  }

  if(strcmp(command_tokens[0],"create_group")==0)
  {
    int new_gid=stoi(command_tokens[1]);
    createGroup(new_gid);
  }

}

void handleClient(int sockfd,char buffer[1024])
{
         int val_read;
        val_read=read(sockfd,buffer,1024);
        if(val_read){ printf("Command read from Client is : %s \n",buffer);
        commandHandler(buffer);
          }
          bzero(buffer,1024);

}

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{ 
     //printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    char *file_name=argv[1];
    FILE *fp;
    char *line=NULL;
    size_t len=0;
    ssize_t read1;

    int tracker_id=atoi(argv[2]);
    char buffer[1024]={0};
    fp=fopen(file_name,"r");
    if(fp==NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    char *token;


    int index=0;

   while ((read1 = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        //printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n", read);
        token=strtok(line," ");
        //printf("IP : ");
        SERVER_IP[index]=token;

        while(token!=NULL)
        {
            //printf("%s\n",token);
            token=strtok(NULL," ");
            if(token!=NULL)
            { //printf("PORT : ");
              SERVER_PORT[index++]=atoi(token);
             }
        }
       // printf("%s\n", line);
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        printf("Server Ip : %s\n",SERVER_IP[i]);
        printf("Server Port : %d \n",SERVER_PORT[i]);
    }


    if(tracker_id==1) //Here the server starts..
    {
        //start tracker 1.
    int server_fd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   struct sockaddr_in addr;
   addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
   addr.sin_port=htons(SERVER_PORT[0]);
   addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(SERVER_IP[0]);
   int addrlen=sizeof(addr);

   bind(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr));
   //listen(server_fd,20);


     size_t buf_sz=50;
     int sockfd;
       listen(server_fd,20);

       printf("\nTracker 1 listening at %s:%d\n",SERVER_IP[0],SERVER_PORT[0]);
       sockfd=accept(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,(socklen_t *)&addrlen);

     while(1)
     {


        thread th1(handleClient,sockfd,buffer);


       th1.join();
       buffer[0]={'\0'};
     } //keep listening forever.
       close(sockfd);
    } //end of if tracker_id==1




    fclose(fp);
    if (line)
        free(line);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);



    return 0;
}
```

Client Code :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <string.h> 
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#define PORT 8081
using namespace std;





int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{   int sock=0,valread;
    string user_input;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    char *hello="create_user 2412 abcd1234";
    char buffer[1024]={0};
    if((sock=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0))<0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creating error\n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port=htons(PORT);
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr))<0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n"); 
        return -1; 
    }   
    char * writable;
    while(1)
  {     
     getline(cin,user_input);



      writable = new char[user_input.size() + 1];
     std::copy(user_input.begin(), user_input.end(), writable);
     writable[user_input.size()] = '\0';
    //hello=user_input.c_str();


    write(sock,writable,strlen(writable));
    //printf("Hello Message sent\n");
    //valread=read(sock,buffer,1024);
    //printf("%s\n",buffer);

  } 
   delete [] writable;
    close(sock);



    return 0;
}
```

[After the client is restarted, server program does not respond.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnJsn.png)

Please help.

Comment: The line `sockfd=accept(server_fd,(struct sockaddr *)&addr,(socklen_t *)&addrlen);` must be inside the while loop.

Comment: And some change must be made inside Client code?